# sorting list of custom classes using linq

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq

I have a custom class

```
Class Item
    Public item As String
    Public Descrip As String
    Public price As String
    Public Bin As String
    Public Total As Decimal
    Public Qty As Integer
End Class
```

now i have another class

```
Public Class Default3
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim c As Int16 = 0
    Dim Item3 As New Item
    Dim Item2 As New List(Of Item)
```

now i am adding the items in Item2 of type Item

```
 Item3.Item = String.Format(record(0))    ' Field "Item"
 Item3.Descrip = String.Format(record(1)) ' Field "Descrip"
 Item3.price = String.Format(record(2))   ' Field "Price"
 Item3.Bin = String.Format(record(3))     ' Field "Bin"

 Item2.Add(Item3)
```

Now how can i sort elements in Item2 according to Item3.Bin?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

```
Item2 = Item2.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Bin).ToList()
```

Or you can you use [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx)

```
Item2.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Bin.CompareTo(y.Bin))
```